# How to use -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay in Command Line Tool

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsobject

I'm trying to use this method on an NSObject in a macOS Command Line Tool.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416176-performselector?language=objc

This works fine in a normal app but when I try to use it in a Command Line Tool nothings happens. I'm keeping my app running by using `dispatch_main()`. What else do I need to do to have this method working on an NSObject?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // ...
    }
    
    dispatch_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try maybe to replace dispatch_main with ```[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:60];``` and see what happens. But show us the ```// ...``` also

Comment: For all asynchronous stuff you need a runloop.

Comment: @vadian Thank you! Adding `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]` is what I needed.

Comment: @vadian : you should create an official answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSURLSessionDataTask completion handler not executing in command line project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49162544/nsurlsessiondatatask-completion-handler-not-executing-in-command-line-project)